# Sorting data on API < 9 not doing anything

Tags: android, sorting, loading

Upon loading my data, I sort it prior to delivering it.

Works perfect, unless Im on a API < 9 device. There, nothing happens.

Does anyone have a legit reason for this? Any workaround?

CollectionUtils.FINISH_TIME is the comparator im using and it looks like this:

```
@Override
    public int compare(Workout lhs, Workout rhs) {
        return (int) (lhs.finishTime - rhs.finishTime);
    }
```

Edit: Snippet where the sorting is performed. 
This is inside a Loaders loadInBack

```
try {
        final String json = DataHandler.read(getContext(), DataFiles.LOGGED_WORKOUTS);
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(json)) {
            final ArrayList<Workout> workouts = Lists.newArrayList(new Gson().fromJson(json,
                    Workout[].class));
                            Collections.sort(workouts, CollectionUtils.FINISH_TIME);
            return workouts;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Utils.logExceptionAndReport(TAG, e);
    }
    return Lists.newArrayList();
}
```

Comment: I don't think so this should be version specific. There must be another issue..

Comment: I kind of agree with you. However what could possibly be the cause when it works perfectly on any device running above API 9?

Comment: The comparable interface has nothing to do with the Android Version. Post some code where this snippet will be called.

Comment: @SteveBenett Ive added some more code.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, Ive got this working now.

Since the finish times are always System.currentTimeMillis() set some time ago, these numbers are often big and when comparing they result in a big positive or negative number.

I changed it so that it compares if(rhs.finishTime > lhs.finishTime) return 1 etc.

I still dont understand why this was working on newer phones, perhaps it was that my data was always inserted at 0 from the start and the sorting never worked. Who knows, its working now and thats whats important.